# Query by setting parameter for mapped entity in JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

My project has two entities User and Item in one to many relationship. The paent User entity is mapped by field "owner" in Item entity which is annotated with Fetchtype.LazyLoad.

Item entity:

```
Item{
     //other fields..

     @Manytoone(@FetchType=LazyLoad)
     User owner;

     //getters and setters...
}
```

Now I am querying to get items whose parent user entity has gender set to Female like below:

```
String queryString="Select i from Item AS i where i.owner.gender='Female'"
Query q=QueryFactory.createQuery(queryString);
List<Item> result=q.getResultList();
```

My question is whether such kind of query is possible?If so, is the annotation LAZYLOAD will have any affect in getting results, since in my understanding,owner field will not be loaded implicitly when loading the Item entities.

Comment: What happens when you test it? Turn SQL logging on to see which SQL queries are executed, change `= Female` to `= 'Female'`, execute the code step by step using your debugger, and see what is loaded at each step.

Comment: I have not tried that.BTW, how do i turn sql logging?My project is google app engine project and I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: you mean, GAE/Datastore? or GAE/CloudSQL? The former will not allow joins in queries

Comment: I am using GAE/Datastore.So my codes as in question wont work?

Comment: Then you should tag your question with GAE. JPA is highly restricted on GAE, and joins in queries, normally supported with JPA, are not on GAE.

Comment: Thankyou.I have followed your suggestions for tag.

Answer (score 1):

GAE does not allow joins, as said in your comments. If you try that you should get an error.

The log should be enabled using standard log4j (internet search its docs) or java.util.logging. They allow a config file in the root of the CLASSPATH to configure how much gets logged. Things can be logged to the console or to a file depending on the config